# Is there a way to download a file using puppeteer on aws lambda?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, puppeteer

I just started learning puppeteer and I'd like to ask if there's a way to download a file using puppeteer with aws lambda? My goal was to send the downloaded file to an s3 bucket. I tried searching the internet but the tutorials are at least 2 years old so I'll roll the dice and ask here. The things I know right now is that I need at least puppeteer core and a headless chromium like @sparticuz/chromium in the node modules? But that's as far as I know since the tutorials I saw weren't really that detailed.

The code below works fine on my local so I'd like a few pointers or people pointing me to the right place to make this code work on aws lambda. Thanks in advance!

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');

async function run() {
    let browser;
    const isHeadless = true;

    try {
        browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: isHeadless });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(2 * 60 * 1000);

        if (isHeadless) {
            const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
            await client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
                behavior: 'allow',
                downloadPath: 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\'
            });
        }
        await page.goto('https://app.website.com/login');
        await page.type('#email', 'email@email.com');
        await page.type('#password', 'password')
        await page.click('[data-cy="submit"]');
        await page.waitForNavigation();

        const el = await page.$x('//*[@id="download_button"]/div/a[1]');
        if (el.length > 0) {
            await el[0].click();
        } else {
            console.log('element not found');
        }
        console.log('download complete.');

    } catch (e) {
        console.error('run failed', e);
    } finally {
        if (browser) {
            await browser.close();
        }
    }
}

run();
```

tldr: I'd like to send a downloaded file from a lambda function to s3 using puppeteer

Comment: Are you putting in a windows path and expect this to work from within a Lambda function?

Comment: @smac2020 I do know that I'll use tmp but as I stated in the post, this works on my local and I'd like some pointers on how to convert this to a lambda function since a lot of the guides are somewhat outdated now